# Linkedin not showing thumbnail from Github-pages hosted website

Tags: html, github, linkedin-api, thumbnails, github-pages

On my linkedIn profile my personal website hosted on Github-pages is not showing [a thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfPAD.png).

I followed the guidelines available on [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en) but It still does not work.

I removed some of personal details from this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

      <meta property="og:title" content="ME"/>
      <meta property="og:image" content="img/snapshot.PNG"/>
      <meta property="og:description" content="A description"/>
      <meta property="og:url" content="URL to the site" />


      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reem+Kufi|Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/grey-white.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <main>
         <div class="intro">STUFF</div>
      </main>
   </body>
</html>
```

Folder structure:

```
index.html
css/
   reset.css
   styles.css
   themes/
         grey-white.css

img/
   snapshot.PNG
   favicon.ico
   circuit-board.svg
```

What am I missing here? Is this a limitation in Linkedin, Github-pages or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add host address before img/snapshot.PNG in og:image tag. This will solve the problem.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it was not needed for my other image resources such as circuit-board.svg and favicon.ico. Doubt it is needed for this image as well?